# Android cannot use support v7

Tags: android, android-appcompat

under Demo it shows `The hierarchy of the type Demo is inconsistent`,
under RecyclerView it shows `The type android.support.v4.view.ScrollingView cannot be resolved`. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files.
How do I resolve this?

```
public class Demo extends RecyclerView {

    public Demo(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
}
```

Comment: try to add android.support.v4 support to the project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same problem. To resolve this, I check the android support library changes and search in what version is added the NestedScrollingChild.

The version is [Android Support Library, revision 22.1.0 (April 2015)](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)

After known the problem, follow this steps:

1. Remove all support library from your project and your workspace (do code backup before!)
2. Import in your workspace again the support library (android-support-v7-appcompat) you ned with the last revision
3. Go to libs directory of your library v7 imported and **delete** the "**android-support-v4.jar**" file.
4. Right click to the project library imported in your workspace. Select "Android Tools" and then click to "Add support library..."
5. Whait process get finished.
6. Go to your project properties, Android, at the bottom click add, select android-support-v7-appcompat, click to Apply. Clean project.
7. Left click to your project, properties, Java Build Path, libraries
8. Click "Add JARs.."
9. Go to android-support-v7-appcompat project, libs directory, and select android-support-v4.jar file. Click OK.
10. Click ok again. Clean project.

It should work.

Comment if you have some trouble.

PD: Sorry for my english ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way work for me.

In my case, it cause by the version of `"android-support-v4.jar"` is too old.

So I copy the file in `"sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\libs\android-support-v4.jar`", and replace my `"android-support-v4.jar"`.